# Documentation for events like input, paste, etc?

Tags: jquery, events

I just discovered jquery has more events it can capture than is listed on the [events page](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/).

I'd like to know more about events like input, paste, and others that aren't in the main jquery documentation. Where are these features documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery event methods like `.click(function(){})` are just shortcuts for `.bind('click',function(){})`.

As stated in the [jQuery bind documentation](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) the first argument to the bind method is the:

> `eventType` A string containing one or more `JavaScript event types`, such as "click" or "submit," or custom event names.

This means that jQuery supports all Javascript event types, though not all of them have shortcut methods.

Here is a [complete list](http://help.dottoro.com/ljfvvdnm.php) of Javascript events. If you need more info search [The MDC (Mozilla's Doc Center)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event) or [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html)